# How to Validate checkbox with onChange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, forms, validation

This is my code

```
function EmailForm() {

  const [emailResult, getEmailResult] = useState(null)
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    title: "",
    from: "",
    fromemail: "",
    subject: "",
    description: "",
    isActive: false
  });


  function handle(e) {
    const newdata = { ...data }
    newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value
    setData(newdata)
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
```

This is checkbox code what changes should i make so that the data true/false reflects in my console or sql

```
          <div className="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" onChange={(e) => handle(e)} checked= 
          {data.isActive} />
          <label>IsActive</label>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hi, just pointing out that its better to write summarized titles, perhaps change it to “how to validate checkbox with onchange” or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes have a [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked) attribute. In your handler, you could check for the type of input you're dealing with and handle the state change accordingly.

```
function handle(e) {
    const newdata = { ...data };
    newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
    setData(newdata);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
```